# Uploader in Create action - Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an asp.net Mvc Project. 
I want to implement a File up_loader to upload images. my File up_loader should create the correct address and fill the `imgURL` field of database. 
my view looks like this

here is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Hotel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateId, "StateId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("StateId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HotelRate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HotelRate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HotelRate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HotelName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HotelName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HotelName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageURL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />


            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 }
```

and here is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,StateId,HotelRate,HotelName,Description,ImageURL")] Hotel hotel,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null) 
        { 

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/hotel"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                hotel.ImageURL = path;

        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Hotels.Add(hotel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.StateId = new SelectList(db.States, "Id", "StateName", hotel.StateId);
        return View(hotel);
    }
```

after saving data everything will be save correctly except `ImgURL`. its data is null after saving and also even before code comes t this command `if (ModelState.IsValid){...}`.

Comment: Show your model class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose whole part

```
if (file != null) 
{ 
//...
}
```

Not working

You should use

```
Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})
```

You don't have file becouse on POST selected file data is not been serialized without `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on `form` tag.